# Build Erlang using gitlab-ci

Tags: erlang, gitlab, travis-ci, gitlab-ci

I have tried to search the Internet a lot but I couldn't find any information on how to build `Erlang` applications on `Gitlab`. I know I can build `Erlang` using `travis-ci` but again I was unable to find how to link my `Gitlab Repository` with `travis-ci`.

All the help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from version 8.0, GitLab Continuous Integration (CI) is fully integrated into GitLab itself and is enabled by default on all projects.

[See documentation](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/ci/README.html)

1. Create Runner
2. Create `.gitlab-ci.yml` into your project root
3. Put into `.gitlab-ci.yml` next code:

---

Example

```
stages:
  - build

build_my_project:
  stage: build
  script:
    - make get-deps
    - make compile
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but if an error occurs in the Erlang shell, the `gitlb runner` still shows `Build succeeded`.

Comment: And where does the erlang shell?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation page "[Test a Clojure application](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/ci/examples/test-clojure-application.html)".

Basically, you've got the Debian package system (apt-get) and you need to install whatever you want to use. You might use [the packages from Erlang Solutions](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/resources/download.html) or you might use [Kerl](https://github.com/kerl/kerl) to install from scratch.

Comment: I think you didnt read my question properly. I dont want to build erlang, I want to build applications written in erlang.

Comment: Yes, my answer describes testing an Erlang application. Specifically, that before you can test your application you must install prerequisites (including the language). If you've already gotten past that part and are having some _specific_ problem, please edit your question to include what you've tried and what part of it isn't working.